# optimizing groupby-agg query using multiprocessing

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset containing 2.2 million records, with an ID and a timestamp column. I have to group the dataset by ID, and calculate the difference between the earliest and the latest timestamp (timestamps are sorted within IDs). The following operation takes about 20 seconds to run on my 8 Core,16 GB machine :-

```
df[['ID','time']].groupby('ID').agg({time : lambda x: x.iloc[-1] - x.iloc[0]}).mean()
```

Having tried and failed at using Dask to parallelize my query(dask doesn't play well with agg), I tried using mp to split my `df` into chunks and apply aggregation parallelly, but I don't know how to ensure that all rows with the same ID end up in the same chunk. This is how I'm currently doing it:-

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import pandas as pd

def get_throughput_time_df(df):
    res = df[['ID','time']] \
    .groupby('ID') \
    .agg({'time' : lambda x: x.iloc[-1] - x.iloc[0]})

    return res

def mult(df):
    p = mp.Pool(processes = 8) 
    split = np.array_split(df,8,axis = 0)
    df_pool_results = p.map(get_throughput_time_df,split)
    p.close()
    result = pd.concat(df_pool_results,axis = 0)
    return result.mean()
```

Questions: -

1.) How do I ensure that my dataset gets split into chunks such that all rows with the same ID end up in the same chunk?

2.) Is there a better way of doing what I am trying to? I think the lambda function used within `agg` can be optimized further,as it's taking up the most time to execute, but I can't see a way of doing it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Forget about multiprocessing. Your extremely slow `groupby.agg` with a lambda can be dropped in favor of GroupBy `min` and `max` (or first, last), which have fast cython implementations and then you can do a single subtraction after, which is vectorized and very fast.

Comment: That is, you should be able to do something really fast like: `df[['ID','time']].groupby('ID')['time'].agg(['first', 'last']).diff(axis=1).iloc[:, -1].mean()`. The last bit of chaining is a bit silly, but you can split it out on your own. (Use min and max if not sorted)

Comment: This worked wonderfully for me. Thanks!